# Highcharts addAxis dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I want to add chart Axis and chart Series dynamically like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addaxis/).

```
$.each(seriesOptions, function(){
        chart.addAxis({
            id: this.name,
            title: {
                text: this.name
            },
            lineWidth: 2,
            opposite: true
        });

        chart.addSeries({
            name: this.name,
            data: this.data,
            yAxis: this.name
        });
    });
```

My solution works quite well: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDLQF/1/)
But after loading the chart, I can only see the yAxis but no series. If Im clicking on a specific range (rangeSelector) - the series becomes visible.
I think there is an issue with the rangeSelector and yAxis? Because when Im removing the rangeSelector I will get an "NodeNotFound" error.

Any suggestions?
Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but your example doesn't work. Regarding your issue - why you are using addSeries and addAxis, while you can add this directly to chart options?

Comment: because I have to addAxis dynamically because  I dont know how many series I will get

Comment: I don't see the difference - just before creating chart loop through seriesOptions like you are doing right now, you should generate two arrays - one with series, one with axes.

Comment: yes, but how to add dynamic generated axes?, how can i add an axis array to my chart without using a foreach?

Comment: But this each is pretty fine. Just BEFORE creating chart create two arrays, for example: `axes = []` and `series = []`. Then in foreach push to that arrays axis and series. Next step is simple, when creating chart set: `series: series, yAxis: axes`.

Comment: ah that works pretty well, thanks a lot! :)